# Aws ECR task looks for image using :latest

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, image, task, amazon-ecr

We have an ecs task that looks for an image with the :latest tag and deploys that image into our cluster.

One of the :latest images were problematic so we deleted it hoping aws might be smart enough to tag the previous image with :latest

However it wasn't. Will our current task fail to run now that it cannot find an image with the tag :latest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the node hosting the task or the task itself stopped/failed for whatever reason, ECS will try to spawn another task on a node and if that node has no locally cached copy of the docker image, that node will try to download the image from ECR and would fail because there's no image tagged as `:latest`.

Comment: oh crud, thanks that's actually really good to know!

Comment: I'll choose this as answer as it was exactly what I was after even though Hussain above was also really helpful!

Comment: thanks @LeslieAlldridge! I'm upvoting Hussain's answer too coz everybody deserves love!

Answer (score 4):

You can download the previous image, tag it with `:latest` and push again.

Alternate is to update the **Task Definition** where the container image is referred for the container.

No ECS doesn't do it automatically because that's might not be what everyone wants or is a standard in anyway. Every image is unique and rollback to previous image might be a wrong requirement. That's why it's not a default behaviour. ECS Task Definition Image documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image

Comment: cool thank you, I had an idea in mind that perhaps on deployment we should update the task definition to use the newly tagged image (e.g. build 123) instead of "latest". It seems like using latest is not the best way to refer to images.

Comment: It is common to use latest tag as long as you're not deleting images frequently from the repo. Or the whole push/delete workflow is properly implemented with corner cases.